# MSBuild: How to add library reference in Visual studio project without build number?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, versioning, visual-studio-project

I faced an error, when I am trying to add NuGet library reference to Visual Studio project.

In Visual Studio project reference specified like:

```
<Reference Include="MyLibrary, Version=6.5.4.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7fb9232453a58fc74, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But, I would like to specify MyLibrary reference despite build number (last digit), e.g. Version=6.5.4.* For me, it does not work, and I am looking for the solution.

It case reference specified with the build number, it fails when NuGet package  updated by build agent with higher build version.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the MyLibrary NuGet package
2. Remove the MyLibrary DLL reference
3. Re-add the MyLibrary NuGet package and let NuGet manage the MyLibrary DLL reference from now on.